# Inconveniences of pointers to static variables

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I often use convenience functions that return pointers to static buffers like this:

```
char* p(int x) {
    static char res[512];

    snprintf(res, sizeof(res)-1, "number is %d", x));

    return res;
}
```

and use them all over the place as arguments to other functions:

```
...
some_func( somearg, p(6) );
....
```

However, this "convenience" has an annoying drawback besides not being thread-safe (and probably many more reasons):

```
some_func( somearg, p(6), p(7) );
```

The above obviously doesn't do what I want since the last two arguments will point to the same memory space. I would like to be able get the above to work properly without to many hassles.

So my question is:

**Is there some magic way I have missed to accomplish what I want without doing cumbersome allocation & freeing?**

***** UPDATE 2010-04-20 *****

Shameless plug: look at my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231317/inconveniences-of-pointers-to-static-variables/2677237#2677237)

I guess it will work but it's also bordering to overkill. Opinions?

Comment: Within the C realm, there's not really any good answer. For some situations, you can get by with requiring the caller to pass a buffer, but that loses much of the convenience.

Comment: It's not just thread-unsafe, you'll get unexpected side effects. Suppose you call the function twice in a row, assigning the results to two different pointers. When you output both strings, you'll get the second value twice, since both pointers point to the same buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate method. Something like this:

```
#define INIT(n) \
 int xi = 0; \
 char *x[n]; \

#define MACRO(s) \
 (++xi, xi %= sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x), x[xi] = alloca(strlen(s)+1), strcpy(x[xi], (s)), x[xi])
```

that I can call like this:

```
INIT(2);
some_func( somearg, MACRO("testing1"), MACRO("testing2"));
```

So the buffers are on the stack without needing any freeing. And it's even thread-safe.

Comment: I've shamelessly made this the correct answer until somebody comes in here and challenges it :)

Comment: TBH, this is a weird way of doing it. I would skip the INIT macro, and just call MACRO twice, each on its own line. Something like this: `char * s1 = MACRO("hello"); char * s2 = MACRO("world"); some_func(s1, s2);` Then again, I would do this without macros in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Well, one widely used approach is to put the responsibility of preparing the memory buffer for the result on the *caller*. The caller can choose whatever method it likes best.

In your case write your `p` as

```
char* p(char *buffer, size_t max_length, int x) { 
  snprintf(buffer, max_length, "number is %d", x); 
  return buffer; 
}
```

and call it as

```
char buffer1[512], buffer2[512];   
some_func( somearg, p(buffer1, sizeof buffer1 - 1, 6), p(buffer2, sizeof buffer2 - 1, 7) );
```

This approach has at least one obvious drawback though: in general case the caller does not know in advance how many characters it needs to allocate for the buffer. If a good constant compile-time value is available, then it is easy, but in more complicated cases an additional effort is required, like providing some kind of "pre-calculation" functionality that returns the required buffer size as a run-time value. (The `snprintf` function actually works that way: you can call it with null buffer pointer and zero buffer size, just to make a fictive run in order to determine the buffer size).

Answer (score 2):

Have the caller provide the buffer (and the size of the buffer).  It's thread safe, and the buffer can usually go on the stack, so you don't bring on the overhead of heap allocation.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you understand this to be thread-unsafe and so long that your logic expect the values returned by the "convenience" methods to only be valid for the duration of a *few* calls to [possibly various] methods, you can maybe extend this convenience in two unrelated and possibly complementary ways.

- Add an extra argument to the convenience methods so these can pass -optionally- a container for the return value  (also add a size_of_passed_buffer argument if such size cannot be implicitly set).   Whenever the caller supplies a buffer, use it, otherwise, use the static buffer.
  BTW, if the buffer passed to the convenience methods are local variables, their allocation will be automatically (and adequately) managed, following the lifespan of the subroutines where the convenience methods are called.
- Use a circular buffer, allowing for a given number of calls before the buffer elements are reused.
  Such a buffer can also be global, i.e. shared with multiple "convenience" methods (which of course also need to a) play nice, thread-wise, and b) share the pointer to next available byte/element in buffer.

  ---

Implementing all this may seem to be

- a lot of work (for the convenience logic), and also
- a potential for several bugs/issues

However, provided that

- the buffer(s) is (are) adequately sized, and that
- the logic using these convenience methods understand the "rules of the game",

this pattern supplies **a simplistic automated heap management system**, which is a nice thing to have in C (which unlike with Java, .NET and other systems does not offer a built in GC-based heap management)

Comment: That sounds appropriate if the data had to persist through several interface returns and callbacks, and overhead were really crucial and requirements set, such as in a real-time driver. But what's the advantage over the caller allocating a buffer on the stack? This is just asking for a buffer overflow.

Comment: Interesting approach. It would provide the oh-so-sought convenience at the cost of implementing this with its inherint dangers (hopefully only once) ;)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  C does not provide any form of automatic heap management, so you're own for tracking allocated memory.  A standard C-like solution is to have the caller provide a buffer, instead of allocating one internally.  Although this just moves the responsibility of tracking memory around, it often ends up in a more convenient place.  You could, I suppose, look in to [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) if you want to get a form of garbage collection in C.

Answer (score 0):

If the args to the helpers are always literals (as in the example), you could use  a macro:

```
#define P(NUMLIT) ("number is " #NUMLIT)

...
somefunc(somearg, P(6), P(7));
...
```

The preprocessor creates a string from the macro argument NUMLIT and appends it to "number is " to create a single string literal, just as

```
"this" " " "string"
```

is emitted as a single string literal, "this string".